# The role of #ifdef and #ifndef

Tags: c-preprocessor

```c
#define one 0
#ifdef one
printf("one is defined ");
#ifndef one
printf("one is not defined ");
```

In this what is the role of `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`, and what's the output?

Answer (score 136):

Text inside an `ifdef/endif` or `ifndef/endif` *pair* will be left in or removed by the pre-processor depending on the condition. `ifdef` means "if the following is defined" while `ifndef` means "if the following is *not* defined".

So:

```
#define one 0
#ifdef one
    printf("one is defined ");
#endif
#ifndef one
    printf("one is not defined ");
#endif
```

is equivalent to:

```
printf("one is defined ");
```

since `one` is defined so the `ifdef` is true and the `ifndef` is false. It doesn't matter what it's defined *as*. A similar (better in my opinion) piece of code to that would be:

```
#define one 0
#ifdef one
    printf("one is defined ");
#else
    printf("one is not defined ");
#endif
```

since that specifies the intent more clearly in this particular situation.

In your particular case, the text after the `ifdef` is not removed since `one` is defined. The text after the `ifndef` *is* removed for the same reason. There will need to be two closing `endif` lines at some point and the first will cause lines to start being included again, as follows:

```
     #define one 0
+--- #ifdef one
|    printf("one is defined ");     // Everything in here is included.
| +- #ifndef one
| |  printf("one is not defined "); // Everything in here is excluded.
| |  :
| +- #endif
|    :                              // Everything in here is included again.
+--- #endif
```

Answer (score 68):

Someone should mention that in the question there is a little trap. `#ifdef` will only check if the following symbol has been defined via `#define` or by command line, but its value (its substitution in fact) is irrelevant. You could even write

```
#define one
```

precompilers accept that. 
But if you use `#if` it's another thing.

```
#define one 0
#if one
    printf("one evaluates to a truth ");
#endif
#if !one
    printf("one does not evaluate to truth ");
#endif
```

will give `one does not evaluate to truth`. The keyword `defined` allows to get the desired behaviour.

```
#if defined(one)
```

is therefore equivalent to `#ifdef`

The advantage of the `#if` construct is to allow a better handling of code paths, try to do something like that with the old `#ifdef`/`#ifndef` pair.

```
#if defined(ORA_PROC) || defined(__GNUC) && __GNUC_VERSION > 300
```

Answer (score 0):

"#if one" means that if "#define one" has been written "#if one" is executed otherwise "#ifndef one" is executed.

This is just the C Pre-Processor (CPP) Directive equivalent of the if, then, else branch statements in the C language.

i.e.
if {#define one} then printf("one evaluates to a truth ");
else
printf("one is not defined ");
so if there was no #define one statement then the else branch of the statement would be executed.

Comment: I'm not sure what this adds that the other answers don't already cover, and your example is not C or C++.

Answer (score -2):

The code looks strange because the printf are not in any function blocks.

Comment: the whole block can be inside a function itself. And welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.