# what does #ifndef _WIN32 signify?

Tags: c, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [the role of #ifdef and #ifndef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744608/the-role-of-ifdef-and-ifndef)

Does

```
#ifndef _WIN32
```

instruct the cpp to omit the code for 32 bit windows platform ?

Answer (score 6):

`#ifndef _WIN32` tells the pre-processor to include the code below it till a corresponding `#endif`, if _WIN32 is not defined.

```
#ifndef _WIN32
#define STR1 "Some String"
#endif
```

The macro STR1 will get included if _WIN32 is not defined and will not get included if _WIN32 is defined. Please note that _WIN32 is a system defined macro. Generally, the code which is not meant for Windows platform or which is generic and cannot be compiled in Windows is placed under such #ifndef _WIN32 macros.

The [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) says _WIN32 will be defined by default for all 32 bit and 64 bit builds.

Answer (score 1):

This directive means "don't include this code when _WIN32 macro defined".
If you define macro _WIN32 only when compile for the Win32 then this code "instruct the cpp to omit the code for 32 bit windows platform".

Comment: `_WIN32` will be defined by all compilers targeting Win32. You don't have to do that yourself.

Comment: I'm not sure about "all compilers".

Answer (score 0):

Well it is a preprocessor directive. It is called compilation constants.

Compiler will consider the piece of code under those #ifndef if the compilation constant(such as, _WIN32) is not defined.

I believe above explanation will help you resolving your query.

To be more specific,

```
#ifndef _WIN32

...
...
...
some code
...
...
...

#endif
```

here if you have not defined _WIN32 (such as #define _WIN32) then the code within that #if...#endif will be compiled.

hope it helps.