# Write a macro function to change the case of a string?

Tags: c++, c, string, macros, preprocessor

// I tried this code

```
 #include<iostream>
 using namespace std;
```

// Function to convert characters
// of a string to opposite case

```
#define case_change(str)\
{\
    int ln = str.length();\
```

// Conversion according to ASCII values

```
 #define for (int i=0; i<ln; i++)\
            {\
                #ifdef (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z'){\
                    str[i] = str[i] - 32;\
                #endif}
                //Convert lowercase to uppercase

                #elifdef (str[i]>='A' && str[i]<='Z')\{\
                    str[i] = str[i] + 32;\
                #endif}\
                //Convert uppercase to lowercase


            #endif}
    }
```

// Driver function

```
int main()
{
    string str = "GeEkSfOrGeEkS";

    // Calling the Function
    case_change(str);

    cout << str;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't wite a macro. Write a function instead.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You might want to have a look at the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn more about writing a good question. In particular, we need a description of what went wrong when you tried to run the code.

Comment: There's no such thing as a macro function. There are macros and there are functions. 99.999% of the time you should prefer a function.

Comment: I wouldn't attempt to use a macro at all for this, in C or C++.   However, in C++, if you're stubborn enough to insist on using a macro, and assuming you're able to use standard header `<cctype>` then `#define case_change(str)  std::transform(std::begin(str), std::end(str), [](int x) -> int {return std::tolower(x) ? std::toupper(x) : (std::toupper(x) ? std::tolower(x) : x);})` will do it.   Note this doesn't rely on characters using an ASCII representation.  It will also work on any collection of `char` for which the compiler can detect start and end, not just strings.

Comment: @john -- the standard defines "function-like macros"; they are often referred to informally as "macro functions".

Comment: @Peter -- that macro isn't quite right; the tests should be `std::islower(x)` and `std::isupper(x)`, not `std::tolower(x)` and `std::toupper(x)`. Don't you hate it that comments can't be edited?

Comment: @PeteBecker - Yep, you're right.   I typed too fast

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have got `if` and `ifdef` confused. `ifdef` is used to test whether a macro has previously been defined, and enable functionality based on that definition. See this question: [The role of #ifdef and #ifndef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744608/the-role-of-ifdef-and-ifndef)

Instead, you are trying to execute a particular piece of code based on a runtime test. For that, you want `if` instead.

As mentioned in comments, it generally considered bad practice to write a macro when you should be writing a function. [Macro vs Function in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104568/macro-vs-function-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')
```

should be

```
if (str[i]>='a' && str[i]<='z')
```

`#ifdef` doesn't make sense because`str[i]` must be evaluated at run time and the macro preprocessor only works at compile time.

Also `#elifdef` is not a legal token. For similar reason to above this should be `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code. I think it will help you

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
    
using namespace std;
    
#define CASE_CHANGE(str) ({        \
    int i = 0;                     \
    string op = "";                \
    while (str[i] != '\0') {       \
        if (isupper(str[i])) {     \
            op += tolower(str[i]); \
        }                          \
        else {                     \
            op += toupper(str[i]); \
        }                          \
        ++i;                       \
    }                              \
    op;                            \
    })

int main() {
    cout << CASE_CHANGE("babu");
}
```

Comment: This does not work for `std::string` since the case when `str[i]='\0'` is an illegal access (i.e., we would have that `i == str.size()`. Could you provide OP with an example that does not assume that `str` is `char *` (or `const char *`)? Also, indenting the macro properly would be a plus!